# InnerHtml of div is always empty

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms, innerhtml

I have next html :

```
<div class="output">
    <div id="divInternet" runat="server" class="issue">
        <!--This message shows up regardless of choice-->
        <p>
            If you operate a service that connects to the internet and intend to collect any...
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

On Server side i try to get `InnerHTML` of `div` with id `divInternet`:

```
var q1Text = divInternet.InnerHtml;
```

but always `q1Text` is empty.

I try to add attribute `runat="server"` to inner `p` but it throws exception that innerHTML must be literal.

---

Expected result - i want to get `<p>` and its content:

```
<p>
    If you operate a service that connects to the internet and intend to collect any...
</p>
```

What have i missed?

---

UPD: i didn't mention on this from start, but now i think it is important.

More detailer content of div :

```
<p>
    If you operate a service that connects to the internet and intend to collect any 
    <a href= "<%=Project.Core.Common.PublisherConfigurationManager.Navigation%>privacy/faq.aspx#16" target="_blank" class="dotlink">personal information</a>...
</p>
```

So there are tag a that contains data from config.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why do you need to get the inner div html?

Comment: If i put your HTML to a sample aspx page and look at `divInternet.InnerHtml` in codebehind i get: `<!--This message shows up regardless of choice-->
        <p>
            If you operate a service that connects to the internet and intend to collect any...
        </p>`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, i want to get just this `<p>
    If you operate a service that connects to the internet and intend to collect any...
   </p>`

Comment: As mentioned, i have already tried your html and it works as expected. Of course `<!--This message shows up...` is included. However, it's not empty as you've stated.

Comment: What sub is the `var q1Text = divInternet.InnerHtml` code in?

Comment: Also, where is that HTML at all? Do you gerenate it dynamically or is it declared statically on aspx?

Comment: Yes---there is a key here that is missing as if you put that HTML in an .aspx page and the code you have in the Page_Load it works...

Comment: @TimSchmelter, this html is on aspx page

Comment: @TonyHinkle, so problem is that i try to get innerHtml on button click?

Comment: @demo: no, that would work also.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, and if this innerHTML contains variable from config?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var q1Text = new StringBuilder();
    divInternet.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(q1Text)));
```

Comment: this didn't help. InnerText and InnerHtml of div is empty

Comment: @demo: `q1Text.ToString()` should give you the **outer** HTML for the `<div>`.